# How to create sequence of integers in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, sequential

I've got dataframe like so:

```
id    year
001   1988
001   1988
001   1988
001   1988
001   1988
002   1972
002   1972
002   1972
002   1972
```

For each `id`, I would like to convert the variable `year` into a sequence beginning from the first observation, increasing by one in each consecutive row. The desired output:

```
id    year
001   1988
001   1989
001   1990
001   1991
001   1992
002   1972
002   1973
002   1974
002   1975
```

How do I do this? A `tidyverse` solution would be preferred. Thanks.

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", "002", "002", "002", "002"),
                 year = c(1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1972, 1972, 1972, 1972))
```

Comment: Can we assume the dataset has only duplicates?  i.e. every row with id `001` will have year `1988` in the initial dataset?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `seq`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(year = seq(first(year), length.out = n()), .by = id)

#   id year
# 1  1 1988
# 2  1 1989
# 3  1 1990
# 4  1 1991
# 5  1 1992
# 6  2 1972
# 7  2 1973
# 8  2 1974
# 9  2 1975
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error in `mutate()`:
! Can't supply `.by` when `.data` is a grouped data frame.

Comment: You need to update `dplyr`, otherwise do: `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(year = seq(first(year), length.out = n()))`

Comment: @Maël OP has updated dplyr thats why the error. The problem is that the data is already grouped. therefore your suggestion with `group_by` works, or OP has to ungroup first before mutating using `.by`

Comment: Even if the solution is working for now. The feature of pre-operational grouping with .by is marked as experimental. Decide on your side, if this is suitable for your use case. Otherwise go with the extra group_by.

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution:

```r
transform(df, year = ave(year, id, FUN = \(x) seq_along(x) + x[1] - 1))

#   id year
# 1  1 1988
# 2  1 1989
# 3  1 1990
# 4  1 1991
# 5  1 1992
# 6  2 1972
# 7  2 1973
# 8  2 1974
# 9  2 1975
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, year := .SD + 1:.N - 1, id]
```

or in case not all years are the same initially per id then you need `first(year)`

```
df[, year := first(year) + 1:.N - 1, id]
```